# Building opencv3 with ffmpeg

Tags: c++, c, opencv, ffmpeg

```
[ 40%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o

In file included from /home/liuge/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:0:

/home/liuge/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function ‘void CvCapture_FFMPEG::close()’:

/home/liuge/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:317:36: 
error: ‘avcodec_free_frame’ was not declared in this scope
         avcodec_free_frame(&picture);
                                    ^
/home/liuge/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function ‘bool CvCapture_FFMPEG::open(const char*)’:

/home/liuge/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:632:43: error: ‘avcodec_alloc_frame’ was not declared in this scope
             picture = avcodec_alloc_frame();
                                           ^

/home/liuge/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:635:41: error: ‘PIX_FMT_BGR24’ was not declared in this scope
                     avpicture_get_size( PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                                         ^

/home/liuge/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function ‘bool CvCapture_FFMPEG::retrieveFrame(int, unsigned char**, int*, int*, int*, int*)’:

.......
```

it works when i type `-D WITH_FFMPEG=OFF`
how do i build CV with FFmpeg?